# what should be parameters of action method when there is foreach loop in your form in view mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, foreach

I am working on a project "Online examination system".  User can give MCQ test here.

Now in my database I have a table named "Question" which contains questions of every subject in the database. When the user selects a subject for an exam, the questions of that subject are stored in var `a` by where query. Now that var `a` is passed to return view.

Then in the Exam view, the name of every field is dynamic and differs by ID column in table which is auto increment primary key.

Every MCQ is submitted to `Exam_Result()` Action method for Checking that its right or wrong.

Now the confusion is in `Exam_Result()` Action method's parameters...  say 20 questions are submitted to `Exam_Result`, andn how should I handle dynamic names in the parameter of `Exam_Result()` ?

### Exam() Action method in home controller:

```
public ActionResult Exam(string sname)
{
    ProjectDatabaseEntities7 obj = new ProjectDatabaseEntities7();
    Question q = new Question();
    try
    {
        var a = obj.Questions.Where(s=>s.Subject_Name.Equals(sname));
        return View(a);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    return View();
}
```

---

### Exam.cshtml View:

```
<form action="/User/Exam_Result">
@foreach (var s in Model)
{
    <div class="col-md-12 well form-group">
        <label>@s.Question1</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="question{@s.Id}" value="@s.Question1" hidden/>
        <input type="radio" name="option{@s.Id}">@s.Option1<br />
        <input type="radio" name="option{@s.Id}">@s.Option2<br />
        <input type="radio" name="option{@s.Id}">@s.Option3<br />
        <input type="radio" name="option{@s.Id}">@s.Option4<br />
    </div>
}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-group-justified" />    
</form>
```

---

### Exam_result() Action Method where the form above is submitting:

```
public ActionResult Exam_Result(string question, string option)
{
    ProjectDatabaseEntities7 obj = new ProjectDatabaseEntities7();
    Question q = new Question();

    try
    {   
        q = obj.Questions.First(x=> x.Question1.Equals(question));

        if(q!=null)
        {
            if (q.Answer == option)
                ViewBag.ans = "right ans";
            else
                ViewBag.ans = "wrong ans";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
    return View();
}
```

### Database table Question:

[image]

Comment: whats wrong with your example?

Comment: i am asking for help about that how to pass multiple records to a view to be used in foreach loop and how to submit that multiple inputs into action method !

Answer (score 2):

Exam_Result can accept your model as a parameter, allowing it to accept anything that your model defines. When you call into your exam function, and you give it your model, you're giving it all of the properties that it needs at once.

```
public ActionResult Exam_Result(YourModelClass model)
```

In your model, you'll just have a property that contains a list of the property that you need N of.

```
public class YourModelClass 
{
    public int ExamId {get; set;}
    public List<Type> ListName { get; set; }
}
```

You can access the list as it is a property of the model in your view:

```
@foreach(var listItem in model.ListName)
{
     @listItem
}
```

To send this information back to the view, you can just return it explicity:

```
return View("ViewName", model);
```

Since you're using Razor, all you need to do to define the model in your view is add this to the top of the page:

```
@model Your.Namespace.YourModelClass
```

For your comment about having different names and values:

```
public class YourCustomType
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public var WhateverElse { get; set; }
}

@foreach(YourCustomType item in model.YourList)
{
     //item.Name
     //item.WhateverElse
}
```

Comment: can you explain it in more details?

Comment: is there any efficient method for sending data from Exam() action method to Exam view? or this will work perfectly?

Comment: This solves for exactly that case. When you return to your view, you can return:

    return View("ViewName", model);

And all of your model data will make it back to the view.

Comment: then how can "name" attribute in radio button grp should differ for every iteration using your way?

Comment: You can define a class that takes the name and whatever other parameters are applied to that, and make that the type of your list. I'll append a case for that for you.

Comment: i have edited my post and added db table image. now see that Exam() action method is sending multiple rows to Exam view then every row sended from Exam() is displayed in Exam view using foreach loop. now i have to send every selected option along with its question to Exam_Result(). Question to find it in db and option to compare it woth answer...now the thing i am not understanding is that how can i check for every mcq anwer with a single click of submit button in form?

Comment: actually i am new to mvc therefore i am facing some problems in picking up you concept. i appreciate your effort.

Comment: could you be more specific about what should i write in Exam(), Exam_Result() action method and in Exam view?

Comment: No worries, man. You don't need to change your controller logic. All you need to do here is encapsulate your names and ids in a class, and create a list of that class in a model class. MVC can be a very challenging design to grasp initially, keep working at it, and you'll make it out on the other side soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

You model binding is wrong. 
First of all don't use entity objects in View page, instead create a custom View model and map entity objects and bind it to view page.

You form `<form action="/User/Exam_Result">` submits a list of `Model` (question) but your action only accepts one question (`question`/`option` parameters) which is wrong. You should change `Exam_Result` action parameter to accept a list of questions

Comment: change parameter to what?